# How to convert number stored as text : Using Jrxml /jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I use jrxml jasper to export my content to .xls file . I am having a filed named `PollutantQuantity` which is persisted as a string in DB.

I am fetching the same and giving those values to .jrxml . I can see the values getting populated correctly without any issue . Now my customer wants to do some `SUM`,`MULTIPLY` functions directly from the exported sheet .

In this case ,since is rendered as text , I can't do any manipultaions.

My Jrxml code snippet is like

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
<field name="pollutantQty" class="java.lang.String" />
<textField>    
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" />
<box leftPadding="10"><pen lineColor="#000000" /><topPen lineWidth="0.5" /><leftPen lineWidth="0.5" /><bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" /><rightPen lineWidth="0.5" />
  </box>                                    
  <textFieldExpression ><![CDATA[$F{pollutantQty}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I am using the property field and also my field emissionQty is declared as string. How can I convert that so that in output excel the emissionQty is 
interpreted as Number.

Comment: Hi , Guys can anyone please post if u have any solution

Comment: Petter,  the below solution worked,  thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define field as a **Number** es. `java.lang.Double`

```
<field name="pollutantQty" class="java.lang.Double" />
```

Use **pattern** in report to display it as you like

```
<textField pattern='###,##0.00'>    
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" />
  <box leftPadding="10"><pen lineColor="#000000" /><topPen lineWidth="0.5" /><leftPen lineWidth="0.5" /><bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" /><rightPen lineWidth="0.5" />
  </box>                                  
  <textFieldExpression ><![CDATA[$F{pollutantQty}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If you can't declare it as a Number (its a String in database), you need to convert the String to a Number es.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Double.parseDouble($F{pollutantQty})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

In this case it can be wise to put a `printWhenExpression` using for example  [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), to avoid errors.

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{pollutantQty}.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")]]></printWhenExpression>
```

or as if statement in `textFieldExpression`

Answer (score 0):

As an extra note to the suggested solution - if you are already dealing with numerical fields (in my case java.math.BigDecimal) and you aren't able to use computation functions in the generated excel file (SUM) - check your JRXML file and see if it contains this property:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
```

The OP has the property but it doesn't contain the **xls** in the string.

Comment: Tried. This does not work